# Como comparo uma entrada em char com um intervalo (0 a 9) sem precisar condições individuais?

Tags: c, char

Estou fazendo um programa que lê uma *string* e quero ignorar os espaços e letras que o usuário digitar (mas tenho que ler as letras i e p e os símbolos matemáticos +-/*^).

O que consegui até agora foi ignorar somente os espaços. Pensei de ao invés de ignorar o que não quero, eu aceitar somente o que quero. Por isso preciso saber como comparar com um intervalo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

  void main()
  {
    char t[10];
    char r[10];
    fgets(t, 10, stdin);
    int i = 0;
    int c = 0;
    for (i=0; i<10; i++){
        if (t[i] !=' '){
            r[c]=t[i];
            c++;
        }
    }
    printf("%s", r);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode fazer assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
    char t[10];
    char r[10];
    fgets(t, 10, stdin);
    int c = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10 && t[i] != 0; i++) {
        if (isdigit(t[i]) || t[i] == 'i' || t[i] == 'p' || t[i] == '+' || 
                t[i] == '-' || t[i] == '*' || t[i] == '/' || t[i] == '^') {
            r[c++] = t[i];
        }
    }
    r[c] = '\0';
    printf("%s", r);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/RN5VvD). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/zxpfonkn-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/MiniParsing.c).

Dei uma simplificada e modernizada. Note que verificar caracteres soltos não tem muito o que fazer a não ser comparar um por um. Claro que poderia criar uma [solução com um *array* dos caracteres válidos](https://ideone.com/QZyl06), mas não acho que compense nesse caso, fica mais curto, mas pode não ser tão bom na performance.

Para verificar os dígitos preferi usar uma função pronta ([`isdigit()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit)). Também poderia comparar por uma faixa (`t[i] >= '0' && t[i] <= '9'`) que deve ser a exata implementação do `isdigit()`.

Arrumei um problema que impede o funcionamento correto em algumas situações que é a falta da finalização da *string* que sempre deve terminar com um nulo. Também agora o laço vai até encontrar um nulo, afinal a *string* pode ser menor que 10 caracteres, sem essa verificação pegaria lixo nesses casos.

Comment: Fiz separado sem utilizar o isdigit (não entendi pra que ele serve) e deu certo, mas na hora de imprimir o vetor na tela sempre imprime um p0 ao final. Você sabe porque isso passou a acontecer?

Comment: Não, eu não sei o que fez.

Comment: O isdigit serve para verificar se o caracter passado é um dígito (ou seja se está entre 0 e 9).

Comment: `isdigit` em algumas implementações é uma consulta a uma tabela hash. Isso permite que seja realizada a operação em um comando.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>  // para printf, fgets
#include <string.h> // para strchr

int main() // tipo de 'main' e' 'int'
{
   // variavel de controle do 'for' que anda no buffer de entrada (lido do teclado)
   int i;

   // variavel de controle do 'for' que anda no buffer de saida (caracteres validos)
   int c;

   // buffer para leitura de linha
   char t[10];

   // buffer de saida, apenas com os caracteres lidos que sao validos
   char r[10];

   // tabela de caracteres validos
   char validChars[] = "01234567890ip+-/*";

   // ponteiro usado como resultado da chamada a 'strchr'
   char* p;

   // leitura de uma linha do teclado
   // no final do buffer vai ter '\n' e '\0'
   // portanto na verdade vai ter no maximo 8 caracteres validos
   fgets(t, 10, stdin);

   // inicializa os indices dos buffers de entrada 'i' e saida 'c'
   // verifica se cada caracter lido no 'fgets' esta' na tabela 'validChars'
   // para no 0 binario que marca o fim do buffer de entrada
   for (i = 0, c = 0; i < 10 && t[i] != 0; i++)
   {
       // strchr procura o caracter 't[i]' na tabela 'validChars'
       // se o caracter 't]i]' for encontrado, 'p' aponta para o caracter na tabela
       // se o caracter nao for encontrado, 'p' fica valendo NULL
       p = strchr(validChars, t[i]);

       if (p != NULL)
       {
           // ok, caracter e' valido, entao acumula no buffer de saida
           r[c++] = t[i];
       }
   }

   // marca final da string de saida
   r[c] = 0;

   // grava string de saida
   printf("%s", r);

   // nao precisa 'return 0;' porque e' o default
}
```